# How to type out what I write in input field when I click a button in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, button, input

So I want to write something in the input textfield and then press the button and show it here `<p>Hello {{inputValue}}</p>` . I DO NOT want to use keyup for this. I am also saving it in localstorage which works right now but not if I remove keyup.

My .ts file:

```
  selector: 'app-dialouge',
  templateUrl: './dialouge.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialouge.component.css']
})

export class DialougeComponent implements OnInit {
  inputValue: string;
  onKeyUp(event){
    this.inputValue = event.target.value;
  }

  saveBtn(): void {
    console.log("btn clicked: " + this.inputValue);
    window.localStorage.setItem("inputValue", this.inputValue);
    window.localStorage.getItem("inputValue");
  };
  clearStorage(){
    localStorage.clear();
    console.log("ls cleared");
  }


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

my template file:

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)" />
<button (click)="saveBtn()">save</button>
<button (click)="clearStorage()">clear</button>

<p>Hello {{inputValue}}</p>
```

Comment: Please do not deface your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngModel` instead of `keyup` into `input`.

change your HTML like below,

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputValue" />
<button (click)="saveBtn()">save</button>
<button (click)="clearStorage()">clear</button>

<p>Hello {{inputValue}}</p>
```

Remove `onKeyUp` method from your ts file.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `[(ngModel)]` to change it with `input`, because it's more proper to use `[(ngModel)]`. `keyup` fires when you released your finger from keyboard.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputValue" />
<button (click)="saveBtn()">save</button>
<button (click)="clearStorage()">clear</button>

<p>Hello {{afterButtonPressedValue}}</p>
```

Create another value to show and type: `inputValue` for typing and `afterButtonPressedValue` for showing in template.

And your ts will be:

```
  selector: 'app-dialouge',
  templateUrl: './dialouge.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialouge.component.css']
})

export class DialougeComponent implements OnInit {
  inputValue: string;
  afterButtonPressedValue = '';

  saveBtn(): void {
    console.log("btn clicked: " + this.inputValue);
    window.localStorage.setItem("inputValue", this.inputValue);
    window.localStorage.getItem("inputValue");
    this.afterButtonPressedValue = this.inputValue;
  };
  clearStorage(){
    localStorage.clear();
    console.log("ls cleared");
    this.afterButtonPressedValue = '';
  }


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```